# How to implement multi-class semantic segmentation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I'm able to train a [U-net](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) with labeled images that have a binary classification.

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to configure the final layers in Keras/Theano for **multi-class** classification (4 classes).

I have 634 images and corresponding 634 masks that are `unit8` and 64 x 64 pixels.

My masks, instead of being black (0) and white (1), have color labeled objects in 3 categories plus background as follows:

- black (0), background
- red (1), object class 1
- green (2), object class 2
- yellow (3), object class 3

Before training runs, the array containing masks is one-hot encoded as follows:

```
mask_train = to_categorical(mask_train, 4)
```

This makes `mask_train.shape` go from `(634, 1, 64, 64)` to `(2596864, 4)`.

My model closely follows the Unet architecture, however the final layers seem problematic, as I'm unable to flatten the structure so as to match the one-hot encoded array.

```
[...]
up3 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2], axis=1)
conv8 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up3)
conv8 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

up4 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1], axis=1)
conv9 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up4)
conv10 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

# here I used number classes = number of filters and softmax although
# not sure if a dense layer should be here instead
conv11 = Conv2D(4, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(conv10)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv11])

# here categorical cross entropy is being used but may not be correct
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

return model
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to modify the final portions of the model so this trains successfully? I get a variety of shape mismatch errors, and the few times I managed to make it run, the loss did not change throughout epochs.

Answer (score 11):

You should have your target as `(634,4,64,64)` if you're using channels_first.
Or `(634,64,64,4)` if channels_last.

Each channel of your target should be one class. Each channel is an image of 0's and 1's, where 1 means that pixel is that class and 0 means that pixel is not that class.

Then, your target is 634 groups, each group containing four images, each image having 64x64 pixels, where pixels 1 indicate the presence of the desired feature.

I'm not sure the result will be ordered correctly, but you can try:

```
mask_train = to_categorical(mask_train, 4)
mask_train = mask_train.reshape((634,64,64,4)) 
#I chose channels last here because to_categorical is outputing your classes last: (2596864,4)

#moving the channel:
mask_train = np.moveaxis(mask_train,-1,1)
```

If the ordering doesn't work properly, you can do it manually:

```
newMask = np.zeros((634,4,64,64))

for samp in range(len(mask_train)):
    im = mask_train[samp,0]
    for x in range(len(im)):
        row = im[x]
        for y in range(len(row)):
            y_val = row[y]
            newMask[samp,y_val,x,y] = 1
```

Comment: I'm using the Theano back end, so that means channels first—do you think the final layers in my model appear correct?

Comment: What defines if channels go first or last is "keras", not theano. The default is channels last.

Comment: yes but I have my Keras set up correctly for Theano in .keras.json, so my concern has turned to the model, since I'm unsure how it should be shaped at the final stages

Comment: To see if your last layer is ok, do a `model.summary()` and see if its output is `(None,64,64,4)`. It seems correct, since you have 4 filters it will give you four channels, but I can't say the convolutions will result in (64,64). If you use `padding = 'same'` in all layers, including the last, it will probably be ok.

Comment: interesting thought, thanks—`.summary()` shows `(None, 4, 64, 64) ` for last layer...

Comment: Ok, then you have `channels_first` indeed, and you just have to shape your `mask_train` exactly as in my answer :)

Comment: I'll try that now—are `softmax` and `categorical_crossentropy`adequate choices at the end of the model?

Comment: If you use softmax, you have to use it in the right axis, adding a layer `Softmax(axis=1)`. That's because you expect more than one `1` result). But unfortunately, I don't know which axis would be proper, I think it's the axis 1, which is the channels axis. (You want only one 1 among the four channels for the same pixel)

Comment: that's helpful, the classes are mutually exclusive (there should not be more than one `1` per pixel)

Comment: I never used softmax in one axis, I don't know how to do it exactly. It's mentioned here, but not explained: https://keras.io/activations/ -- In the worst case, you'd have to add a Lambda layer just for using that softmax function at the end of your model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143914/discussion-between-pepe-and-daniel).

Comment: Why is the background needed as a separate class to be predicted?

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but you should try

```
mask_train = to_categorical(mask_train, num_classes=None)
```

That will result in `(634, 4, 64, 64)` for `mask_train.shape` and a binary mask for each individual class (one-hot encoded).

Last conv layer, activation and loss looks good for multiclass segmentation.